# Euler Product Formula - Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

For $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\sigma = \Re(s)>1$,
$$\zeta(s)  = \prod\limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$

My question is: is the above correct? Or should the $s$ be replaced with $\sigma$?

Also: 
For all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(s)>1$, $\zeta(s) \neq 0$.

Proof:

For $\sigma=\Re(s)>1$, 
$$\frac{1}{|\zeta(s)|} = \left|\prod\limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)\right| \leq \prod\limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{p^{\sigma}}\right) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma}} \leq1+ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^{\sigma}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma -1} $$
Hence $|\zeta(s)| > \frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}>0$.

I don't get why the inequalities hold. I can see the integral is from the integral test.

Comment: The middle term in the chain of inequalities is wrong, it ought to be $$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{p^{\sigma}}\biggr).$$

Comment: Ah yes but why is the inequality true?

Comment: Which inequality? One of them is true because $\lvert 1 - p^{-s}\rvert \leqslant 1 + \lvert p^{-s}\rvert$ by the triangle inequality, and $\lvert p^{-s}\rvert = p^{-\operatorname{Re} s} = p^{-\sigma}$ gives you the middle term. The next inequality is true because if you multiply out the product, you get the sum over the squarefree $n$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am still confused about whether to use sigma or s in the euler product formula? Some books state one and some the other.

Comment: You must use $s$. Otherwise you'd get a function that doesn't depend on the imaginary part of its argument - and such a function is holomorphic if and only if it is (locally) constant.

Comment: So everything I have stated in my post is correct?

Comment: Last thing: I don't see how the strict inequality is achieved? Square free n?

Comment: Everything is correct after fixing the mentioned issue. We have the strict inequality because e.g. $\frac{1}{4^{\sigma}}$ and $\frac{1}{18^{\sigma}}$ don't appear in the sum you get from multiplying out the product, since $4$ and $18$ are divisible by the square of a prime (i.e. they are not squarefree).